# Can 802.1X, EAP and RADIUS work together?

Tags: authentication

So this is an academic question I came up with while researching the topic.

```
Can 802.1X, EAP and RADIUS work together to provide a secure authentication?
```

If yes, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it can, it's actually quite common setup. It is mostly used in enterprises for example using Windows Server RADIUS. Some info for example here: https://documentation.meraki.com/MR/Encryption_and_Authentication/Configuring_RADIUS_Authentication_with_WPA2-Enterprise. It's quite difficult and complicated but once setup it works and makes the wifi a lot more secure. Never did it myself but it used to be in one company I used to work for, however it worked only with Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reasons why they can't work together, especially when they are different things?

**EAP** -- *Extensible Authentication Protocol*. It is just a PROTOCOL which is used by 802.1x authentication server (RADIUS, for example) and client to authenticate each other.

**RADIUS** -- *Remote Authentication Dial-In User Service*. It is SERVICE which use one or more authentication protocols used by clients to authenticate themselves. There are several industrial authentication protocols, which include but not limited to: (from less secure to more secure) **PAP**, **SPAP**, **CHAP**, **MS-CHAP**, **MS-CHAPv2**, **EAP-TLS**.